# Evaluate mathematical expression within string

Tags: java, android, math, evaluate

I'm developing an Android app that i get an String with the mathematical expression i have to calculate, i did it to convert the letters into the numbers i need, but what is the best way to evaluate this?

Nothing too complicated, the formulas are like those:
`((A * 2 + B * 3 + C * 5) / 10) + D`

EDIT:
Just found that guy, very simple API, works like a charm
http://code.google.com/p/symja/wiki/MathExpressionParser

Comment: What have you tried? Also, isn't this more a Java question that has nothing to do with Android specifically?

Comment: I thought about making a complete "parser", but it seems too complicated for an expression like that. I searched about JEP, but it is commercial now, and JEval, but seems deprecated.. so i want to know something used nowadays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want some sort of math [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser).

Fun to roll your own, or there are plenty of hits on google: https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=16&gs_id=7&xhr=t&q=java+math+parser

Comment: Using the proper words are much easier hehehe, i'm editing the post with the solution i found!