# Simple library for calculator in java (Android)

Tags: java

Is there any simple library in java which can parse a string as input and produce result after evaluating the input string. 
Such as- I will give a `String` like `5+5*(4/2)-7+1`
and any of the library method will return me the output: `9`.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15173681/1113392) . see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15174060/1113392)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Comment: Please try to perform at-least one google search before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java provides a built-in JavaScript syntax processing:

```
javax.script.ScriptEngineManager mgr = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager();
javax.script.ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String res = "5+5*(4/2)-7+1";
System.out.println(engine.eval(res));
```